# Building a REST form to send data on blur

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

I'm working on building a form where each field entered will send a portion of the object to the server and wait for a response back on blur.  My issue at the moment is that state is not updating quick enough before the user moves to the next input field.  The scenario is:

1. User types info into the field
2. User goes to the next field
3. During this moment, a REST call is being made carrying an object of what the user has typed in
4. The response comes back carrying data to fill in the next field
5. However, at times, it seems the response wasn't quick enough or state wasn't updated fast enough so the next field is not pre-filled in

I'm hoping someone can give me some assistance on what the best approach is here to help speed things up.  I can provide some code, but I'm hoping more for some guidance rather than code answers.

Regarding the axios post call:

```
try {
  await this.plansApi
    .compileFields({ obj, carrier, benefitQuery })
    .catch(error => {
      const { required } = error.response.data;
      const { validation } = error.response.data;
      const arr = [];
      if (required !== undefined) {
        required.forEach(item => {
          arr.push(item.name);
        });
        this.setState({ required: arr });
      }
      if (validation !== undefined) {
        validation.forEach(item => {
          arr.push(item.name);
        });
      }
      const check = _.find(goldenListKeys, { name: 'loadingRate' });
      if (check !== undefined) {
        Object.assign(obj.inputData, { loadingRate: 1 });
      }
    });
} catch (err) {
  process.stdout.write(err);
}
```

Comment: When you look in the network tab of your developer console, how long does the REST call take? 1 second? Milliseconds? Just wondering....thanks

Comment: Hey, do you block the next field before a response from the API comes?

Comment: Please post your code if you'd like people to check for performance issues.  Generally speaking, it sounds like you're sending an asynchronous request but aren't waiting for the result.  I would suggest "pausing" the UI and showing some sort of loading icon while you wait for the previous result.

Comment: @NickyTheWrench milliseconds.  It's very fast in the response, but at times the pre-fill still doesn't get filled in fast enough by the time the user clicks into the next input

Comment: @BohdanSviripa not at this time, although I'm starting to think that's a possible solution.

Comment: Yeah, as @prieber said, it sounds like you are not awaiting your response properly.

Comment: @prieber, do you mean an async/await call?  At the moment, I'm only doing a standard axios post and moving on.

Comment: I've posted some code, but it's a bit difficult to summarize.

Comment: @pingeyeg I can't help with the react/node stuff but from a high level yes, you'd want to wait for the response of the async call so you can populate the next field with it's result.

Comment: I agree the guys above, I would consider how much involvement you need in your ux if you need to contact the server every input. Can you split this form out and make it consociational? Then you could lazy load the form and the data to load it..